# Do I need multiple ArrayLists for this program?

Tags: java, arraylist, ranking

I have to make a program that reads in a file of favorites, such as favorite animals. So say it reads in a file that says "Dog, Cat, Fox", 1 on each line. Those are then put into an Arraylist. After the user is prompted to either add or remove any, they are then asked to rank them. Heres where I'm confused- To reorder/rank the lines of the arraylist, would I need a second ArrayList to put the ranking into? Also, after they are ranked, they are asked to add a comment for each one, such as for cats-"I'm allergic to cats" or something like that. Would I need a 3rd Array list for these comments? Heres a sample output-

‘Favorite’ | Rank | Comments from this round (plus all previous comments)

Heres my code right now if you kind of wanna see where I'm going- it doesnt all work but you'll get the gist of it

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList <String> favoriteAnimals = new ArrayList <String>();
        boolean repeat = true;
        while (repeat) {

            System.out.println("Enter the name of the file which contains your favorite animals ");
            String fileName = input.nextLine().trim();

            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {

                String line;
                System.out.println("Here are your favorite animals according to the file:");  
                 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {    
                   System.out.println(line);   
                   favoriteAnimals.add((line));
                 }                                                

                 System.out.println("Add more? (y/n)");
                 if (input.next().startsWith("y")) {
                     System.out.println("Enter : ");
                     favoriteAnimals.add(input.next());
                 } else {
                    break;
                 }
                 for (int i = 0; i < favoriteAnimals.size(); i++) {
                     System.out.println(favoriteAnimals);
                 }

                     System.out.println("Remove an animal?");

                     if (input.next().startsWith("y")) {
                         System.out.println("Which animal would you like to remove");
                            String removeAnimal = input.nextLine();
                            int index = favoriteAnimal.indexOf(removeAnimal);
                            favoriteAnimals.remove(index);
                            System.out.println(favoriteAnimals);
                     }
                     else {
                         break;
                     }

                     ArrayList <String> ranking = new ArrayList <String>();
                    int size = favoriteAnimals.size();
                     String first = favoriteAnimals.get(0);
                    System.out.println("What is your ranking of " + first + " out of " + size +"?");                 


            }



            catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.println("Your file does not exist!: " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                repeat = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use inheritance, where top animal have certain behavior like their rank as position, comment then all your cat, dogs class may inherit from it and then add them to the array list.

Answer (score 1):

In all likelihood, you are supposed to write a small `class Animal` with fields like `String name`, `String comment`, etc. and then have an `ArrayList<Animal>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with Object Oriented OO, Then it is recommended to use classes to encapsulate the data structure you have, I wrote a simple example and I hope it will help you to solve the problem:

**Animal class**

```
package com.stackoverflow.q1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Animal {

private String name;
private Integer rank;
private List<String> comments=new ArrayList<String>();

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public Integer getRank() {
    return rank;
}
public void setRank(Integer rank) {
    this.rank = rank;
}
public List<String> getComments() {
    return comments;
}
public void setComments(List<String> comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Animal [name=" + name + ", rank=" + rank + ", comments="
            + comments + "]";
}
}
```

**Main class**

```
package com.stackoverflow.q1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Animal> animals= new ArrayList<Animal>();

    Animal dog=new Animal();
    dog.setName("dog");
    dog.setRank(1);
    dog.getComments().add("Comment 1");

    Animal horse=new Animal();
    horse.setName("horse");
    horse.setRank(2);
    horse.getComments().add("Comment 1");


    Animal cow=new Animal();
    cow.setName("cow");
    cow.setRank(1);
    cow.getComments().add("Comment 1");

    animals.add(dog);
    animals.add(horse);
    animals.add(cow);


    for(Animal animal:animals){
        System.out.println(animal);
    }

}

}
```